# Remove backslash \ from string using preg replace of php

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, stripslashes

I want to remove the backslash alone using php preg replace.

For example: I have a string looks like

```
$var = "This is the for \testing and i want to add the # and remove \slash alone from the given string";
```

How to remove the `\` alone from the corresponding string using php `preg_replace`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled (`\\\\` PHP string) in [**preg_replace**](http://de3.php.net/preg_replace)

```
echo preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $var);
```

Answer (score 23):

why would you use preg_replace when str_replace is much easier.

```
$str = str_replace('\\', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also use stripslashes() like,

```
<?php echo stripslashes($var); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\(.?)/', '$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me!!

```
preg_replace("/\//", "", $input_lines);
```

Comment: This will capture slash but not backslash.